# Python Tkinter return self.func(*args) and TypeError:list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, tkinter, xlrd

The goal is to extract excel data and write it to a text file, based on an input through tkinter. The Tkinter box is popping up, but when the entry input is given, it produces an error in the terminal.

I have tried changing the line 30 int or float.

Thank you for any help you can give.

The code below is creating this error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
    32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "c:/Users/bob/Dropbox/Financial/PERSONAL FINANCES/budget.py", 
    line 30, in click
        result = np.array(sheet.cell_value(i,budget_col))
      File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 419, in cell_value
        return self._cell_values[rowx][colx]
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My code:

```
    import os
    from tkinter import *
    import time
    import xlrd
    import numpy as np

    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    def click(): 
        file_location = 'C:/Users/bob/Dropbox/Financial/PERSONAL FINANCES/NEW DOUBLE ENTRY PERSONAL.xlsx'
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
        sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(6) 

        budget_col = textentry.get() 

        excel_col1 = np.array([])
        array_length = sheet.nrows
        for i in range(array_length): 
            result = np.array(sheet.cell_value(i,0)) 
            excel_col1  = np.append(excel_col1,[result]) 

        excel_col2 = np.array([])
        for i in range(array_length): # 0 to total rows
            result = np.array(sheet.cell_value(i,1)) 
            excel_col2  = np.append(excel_col2,[result]) 

        excel_col_bud_col = np.array([])
        for i in range(array_length): # 0 to total rows
            result = np.array(sheet.cell_value(i,budget_col)) 
            excel_col_bud_col  = np.append(excel_col_bud_col,[result])

#Writing text file to desktop
# CREATING THE textfile:
created_name = '\curr_budget.txt'
if os.name == 'nt':
    desktop = str(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop'))
    query_if_windows = "windows"
else:
    desktop = str(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop'))
    query_if_windows = "not windows"
filename = desktop + created_name

text_file = open(filename,"w")

text_file.write(time.strftime("%c\n"))
text_file.write("\n")
text_file.write('Accounts - Budget\n')
text_file.write("\n")

for n in range(4,sheet.nrows-2): 
    x = excel_col_bud_col[n]
    y = excel_col2[n]
    z = excel_col1[n]

    text_file.write(z + "  " + x + "  " + y)#,"{bud:8.8} {name}".format(name=y,bud=x))
    text_file.write("\n")

text_file.write("\n")
text_file.write('Note, some debit card transactions will take a few days so will not appear above\n')
text_file.close()

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Print Budget to Desktop")
    window.configure(background="white")
    Label (window,text="Enter column across, starting at 0, where this month's budget is located", bg="white", fg = "black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

    textentry = Entry(window, width=20,bg="white") #column '15' for August budget (starts at 0)
    textentry.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

    Button(window, text="Print Budget to Desktop",width=23,command=click) .grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error telling you precisely what the problem is. It is saying you need to pass an integer rather than a string to a particular function. That is happening because of these two lines:

```
budget_col = textentry.get() 
...
result = np.array(sheet.cell_value(i,budget_col))
```

`budget_col` is a string, but `sheet.cell_value` requires an integer. You need to convert the value you get from `textentry.get()` to an integer before you can pass it to that function.

Comment: Thank you very much, that has sorted the problem! :)